# SQL Developer 4 automatically add semicolon (;) to end of statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Specifically using SQL Developer 4.0.1.14 and I'm looking for a solution to automatically add a semicolon to the end of the current line that the cursor is on. Yes, I could hit the "END" key and then the ";" key, but I thought I could be more efficient. The "END" key just seems so far away.

Some things I've tried or looked into:

1. I've looked into creating shortcut key commands, but can't figure that one out.
2. No idea what "Smart End" does, but that's not it.
3. Looked into creating a macro, but my install instance is missing is whatever is needed to make that happen.
4. A lot of forums mention something called "AutoSelect Statement" by going to: Tools -> Preferences -> Window Types -> SQL Window and check "AutoSelect statement". HOWEVER, this appears to be for "PL/SQL" Developer and NOT "SQL" Developer.

I'm open to any other ideas or anyone can help with creating a "Shortcut Key" which I think would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

instead of that, just mouse-select your statement, and ctrl+enter to execute - that will execute what's highlighted and negate the need for a statement delimiter

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help too much with our multi-paragraph queries. And just slows you down when you're trying to know out a handful of update statements, etc. We were already aware of the triple-click to highlight an entire row.